# How to know when a schedule() call is returning because of a signal?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, signals, linux-device-driver

In a device driver for some PCI hardware, I have an `ioctl` call that waits for an incoming interrupt on the PCI bus. Using `wait_queue_head_t`, I put the task to sleep by calling `schedule()`.

Then, the `irq_handler` function wakes up this task when the interrupt is raised on the PCI bus. Everything seems to work correctly.

My question is how to differentiate whether the `schedule()` call is returning because of my `irq_handler` function wake it up, or because some signal has been send?

Do I have to handle it by myself with flags in the `irq_handler` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this, after the `schedule` call:

```
if (signal_pending(current)) {
    retval = -EINTR;
```